# Counting number of pixels in a cluster (Kmeans color detection)

Tags: python, cluster-computing, counter, k-means

I'm making a code that is analyzing an image and finding the three most dominant colors using `KMeans` clustering. The code works fine but I want to count the number of pixels in the three clusters.

code:

```
class Cluster(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.pixels = []
        self.centroid = None


    def addPoint(self, pixel):
        self.pixels.append(pixel)


    def setNewCentroid(self):
        R = [colour[0] for colour in self.pixels]
        G = [colour[1] for colour in self.pixels]
        B = [colour[2] for colour in self.pixels]

        R = sum(R) / len(R)
        G = sum(G) / len(G)
        B = sum(B) / len(B)

        self.centroid = (R, G, B)
        self.pixels = []        
        return self.centroid


class Kmeans(object):
    def __init__(self, k=2, max_iterations=5, min_distance=2.0, size=200):
        self.k = k
        self.max_iterations = max_iterations
        self.min_distance = min_distance
        self.size = (size, size)


    def run(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.image.thumbnail(self.size)
        self.pixels = numpy.array(image.getdata(), dtype=numpy.uint8)

        self.clusters = [None for i in range(self.k)]
        self.oldClusters = None

        randomPixels = random.sample(self.pixels, self.k)

        for idx in range(self.k):
            self.clusters[idx] = Cluster()
            self.clusters[idx].centroid = randomPixels[idx]

        iterations = 0
        while self.shouldExit(iterations) is False:

            self.oldClusters = [cluster.centroid for cluster in self.clusters]
            print iterations

            for pixel in self.pixels:
                self.assignClusters(pixel)

            for cluster in self.clusters:
                cluster.setNewCentroid()

            iterations += 1
        return [cluster.centroid for cluster in self.clusters]


    def assignClusters(self, pixel):
        shortest = float('Inf')
        for cluster in self.clusters:
            distance = self.calcDistance(cluster.centroid, pixel)
            if distance < shortest:
                shortest = distance
                nearest = cluster

        nearest.addPoint(pixel)


    def calcDistance(self, a, b):
        result = numpy.sqrt(sum((a - b) ** 2))
        return result


    def shouldExit(self, iterations):
        if self.oldClusters is None:
            return False

        for idx in range(self.k):
            dist = self.calcDistance(
                numpy.array(self.clusters[idx].centroid),
                numpy.array(self.oldClusters[idx])
            )
            if dist < self.min_distance:
                return True

        if iterations <= self.max_iterations:
            return False

        return True
```

Is there a way that I can count how many pixels that is assigned to each cluster? I don't want how many that has the same value, just the total number.

Comment: Can't you just sum the index values of the pixels in each cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, you want to do

```
for cluster in self.clusters:
    print len(cluster.pixels)
```

for each cluster?

Comment: Then it looks like this: 
>>print len(pixels)
>>3
It is in a loop wich cycles through all the pixels so i guess i need to make some variable like  x =+ 1 every time it cycles through. But all three clusters is in the same loop so i always end up with x = 30000 (all the pixels in the image 200x150.

Comment: Loop over clusters, not all pixels. Or count clusters separately, of course!

Comment: Your variable naming is misleading. "pixels" is plural, but aoparently you only store one pixel in it? It should be named `pixel` or `color_components` then

Comment: Yes, i only store one pixel in it. And in my actual code it is named pixel, my bad for writing pixels in the question. But thanks for the feedback, i'll try to count the clusters separately.

Comment: It often helps if you put part of your actual code into the question. For example to see the data structures you are using. Many k-means implementations do give you access to a list of objects in each cluster, which would have a size, i.e. `len(cluster == 1)` etc.

Comment: That is a good idea, so i updated the question with part of my code. You can have a look now to better understand what I am struggling with.

Comment: It's literally `len(cluster.pixels)` what you need. I'm impressed by the amount of code you wrote, but you really should benchmark this compared to other solutions. The Python interpreter is rather slow, and performance will not be very good if you do all the heavy lifting in Python. You don' need the `sqrt` - k-means uses least-squares.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! Another problem I have is that the result prints out a list with the dominant colors. Ex like this [(255,55,50),(145,45,40)]. But the colors are in random order, not the most dominant first, and so on. Is there a way I can sort the list from most dominant and down, that you can think of?

Comment: The program is to be used with a webcam to take a picture and analyze it every 30 minutes so I don't think the interpreter being slow is going to be a problem?

Comment: Sort them by the length prior to printing?